# Parsing json in JQuery Ajax Call From PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have seen a bunch of different ways to call a php script via ajax that returns json but i cant seem to get any working  I was curious if someone could help me.

Here is my PHP script:

```
//database connection stuff....
$query = "SELECT * FROM  weather limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
// get data and store in a json array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[] = array(
        'zip' => $row['zip'],
        'temp' => $row['temp'],
        'time' => $row['time']
      );
}

echo json_encode($orders);
```

Next here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'getweather.php',
            type : 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

                    alert(data['zip']);

                }

            }
        });


    });
```

With this i just get 10 alerts that say undefined.  Can someone please help me figure out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Craig

Comment: You are not using your x. Try `data[x]['zip']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` is an array of arrays, you need to index the outer array before the inner array:

```
alert(data[x]['zip'])
```

Comment: i knew it'd be something simple. Thanks!